# How to change a storage device to charge in an off-grid microgrid via PowerWorld simulator

Tags: microgrid

I am having trouble figuring out this: setting up an energy storage device on charge mode via PW.

So, I have designed an off-grid microgrid that I uploaded a photo of to speak for itself.

[image: Diagram]

As you can see there is an energy device that I install in every bus to find an optimal placement. What are the steps to make this device work on charge mode?